# If form field value is blank I want to hide this from the generated report if it is left blank

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Basically I am trying to create a form that once the fields are generated it compiles a report. I have managed to so far to get it to do everything I want it to do except if the form field is blank to hide the section in the generated report div below. I have spent quite a lot of time on this form and I'm not sure what I need to include for you to be able to help me, so I apologise for the screen dump below.
Please note I have removed the website URL from here but it is still in my code.

```
<script>
function check() {
  document.getElementById("text1").innerHTML = document.myform.Topic.value;
  document.getElementById("text2").innerHTML = document.myform.Info.value;
  document.getElementById("text3").innerHTML = document.myform.Summary.value;
  document.getElementById("text4").innerHTML = document.myform.Room.value;
  document.getElementById("text5").innerHTML = document.myform.PM.value;
  document.getElementById("text7").innerHTML = document.myform.PM.value;
  document.getElementById("text6").innerHTML = document.myform.Room2.value;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#generated").hide(); 
  $("#btn").click(function() {
     $("#generated").show();
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#p3").hide(); 
  $("#btn").click(function() {
     $("#p3").show();
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#cbtn").hide(); 
  $("#btn").click(function() {
     $("#cbtn").show();
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#textbox").hide(); 
  $("#btn2").click(function() {
     $("#textbox").show();
  });
});

function myFunction() {
   var element = document.getElementById("form2");
   element.classList.toggle("darkmode");
   var element = document.getElementById("texta");
   element.classList.toggle("darkmode1");
   var element = document.getElementById("textb");
   element.classList.toggle("darkmode1");
   var element = document.getElementById("textc");
   element.classList.toggle("darkmode1");
   var element = document.getElementById("textd");
   element.classList.toggle("darkmode1");
   var element = document.getElementById("texte");
   element.classList.toggle("darkmode1");
   var element = document.getElementById("textf");
   element.classList.toggle("darkmode1");
   var element = document.getElementById("generated");
   element.classList.toggle("darkmode2");
}

function copyRedirect() {
  copyClipboard(); // calling function copyClipboard()
  myFunction1(); // calling function myFunction1()
}
function copyClipboard() {
  var elm = document.getElementById("generated");
  // for Internet Explorer

  if(document.body.createTextRange) {
    var range = document.body.createTextRange();
    range.moveToElementText(elm);
    range.select();
    document.execCommand("Copy");
  }
  else if(window.getSelection) {
    // other browsers

    var selection = window.getSelection();
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNodeContents(elm);
    selection.removeAllRanges();
    selection.addRange(range);
    document.execCommand("Copy");

  }
}

function myFunction1() {
  if(confirm("Your report has been copied to your clipboard, would you like to proceed to the forums?")) document.location = 'https://*******';
  }
</script>
```

```
<html>

<body>
  <br>
  <div class="buttonPlace">
    <button id="darkbtn" onclick="myFunction()">Switch Mode</button>
  </div>
  <div id="form2" class='form1'>
    <form name='myform'>
      <h1> Report Generator</h1>
      <br>
      <p id='p1' style="margin-left:30px;">Topic</p>
      <textarea id="texta" name='Topic' cols="110" rows="2" value="" placeholder="Name, Infraction, Action Taken"></textarea>
      <p id='p1' style="margin-left:30px;"> Info</p>
      <textarea id="textb" name='Info' cols="110" rows="6" value="" placeholder="Chatter Information"></textarea>
      <p id='p1' style="margin-left:30px;"> Summary</p>
      <textarea id="textc" name='Summary' cols="110" rows="6" value="" placeholder="Report Summary"></textarea>
      <p id='p1' style="margin-left:30px;"> #Room</p>
      <textarea id="textd" name='Depression' cols="110" rows="6" value="" placeholder="Logs from #Room (if applicable)"></textarea>
      <p id='p1' style="margin-left:30px;">PM</p>
      <textarea id="texte" name='PM' cols="110" rows="6" value="" placeholder="PM Logs (if applicable)"></textarea>
      <button id="btn2" onclick="check(); return false">Add PM</button>
      <div id='textbox'>
        <p id='p1' style="margin-left:30px;">PM</p>
        <textarea id="textg" name='PM' cols="110" rows="6" value="" placeholder="PM Logs (if applicable)"></textarea>
      </div>
      <p id='p1' style="margin-left:30px;">#Room2</p>
      <textarea id="textf" name='RA' cols="110" rows="6" value="" placeholder="Logs from #Room2 (if applicable)"></textarea>
      <div class="btn-block">
        <p><button id='btn' type='submit' onclick='check(); return false'>Generate Report</button></p>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div id="head1" class="Div1">
    <h1 id='p3'>Report</h1>
    <div id="generated" class="generatedReport">
      <p class="gen">Topic:</p>
      <p id='text1'></p>
      <p class="gen">[b][size=150]Info[/size][/b]</p>
      <p id='text2'></p>
      <p class="gen">[b][size=150]Summary[/size][/b]</p>
      <p id='text3'></p>
      <p class="gen">[b][size=150]#Room[/size][/b]</p>
      <p id='text4'></p>
      <p class="gen">[b][size=150]PM[/size][/b]</p>
      <p id='text5'></p>
      <p class="gen">[b][size=150]PM[/size][/b]</p>
      <p id='text7'></p>
      <p class="gen">[b][size=150]#Room2[/size][/b]</p>
      <p id='text6'></p>
    </div>
    <button id='cbtn' onclick="copyRedirect()">Copy Report</button>
  </div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, you want to submit a report to a clipboard (another div), and if the user doesn't fill out that form field, you don't want that field added to the clipboard?

Comment: Side note: know that you can place all the element show/hide functionality inside one `$(document).ready(function()...` handler.

Comment: It's not clear why you want to copy the report to the clipboard.

Comment: Tip: attach event handlers in javascript, not in the HTML. Thus you can avoid functions in the global namespace.

Comment: Basically, I want the report to generate in a div below the form once completed so it can be reviewed and then it can then be copied to the clipboard and pasted elsewhere. I hope this makes sense and thanks for you help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following lines to the bottom of the `check()` function:

```
$('.gen').each(function() {
    $(this).next('p').addBack().toggle($(this).next('p').text() !== '');
});
```

In addition:

1. You should be looking to attach event handlers in Javascript/jQuery rather than as HTML attributes. Thus you will avoid the need for functions in the global namespace.
2. A lot more can be done in jQuery to simplify the code and make it more readable/maintainable.

**Explanation**

`$('.gen').each(...)` loops through the report's `<p class="gen">...</p>` elements (Topic, Info etc).

For each of those elements, the expression `$(this).next('p').addBack()` creates a jQuery collection comprising the element itself and the immediately following `<p>...</p>` element. Then `.toggle()` is called on that collection.

[jQuery's `collection.toggle()` method](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/) has several variants, in this case `collection.toggle(display)`, where `display` is a boolean. `true` causes `collection` to be shown and `false` causes `collection` to be hidden.

Here, the expression `$(this).next('p').text() !== ''` returns `true` if the next `<p>...</p>` element is empty or `false` if not empty.

So, the outcome of passing the calculated boolean to `.toggle()` is to show/hide the original `<p class="gen">...</p>` and its next `<p>...</p>` element, depending on whether the `<p>...</p>` element is empty or not empty.

You could also write ...

```
$('.gen').each(function() {
    var gen_and_next_p_element = $(this).next('p').addBack();
    var next_p_text = $(this).next('p').text();
    if(next_p_text !== '') {
        gen_and_next_p_element.show();
    } else {
        gen_and_next_p_element.hide();
    }
});
```

... which is arguably easier to understand, but also rather long-winded.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I added it and now instead of showing only the fields with input value, it is only showing me the fields without any value

Comment: That's because I made a teeny-weeny mistake!! Edited :-)

Comment: Thankyou very much it now works!! I know I need to work on my coding but this is the first thing I have ever done so im proud of it. I will look into using more JS/JQ in future projects!

Comment: Be proud, definitely. See if you can understand my jQuery. It's not the simplest. If you can't get it, I'll edit-in an explanation.

Comment: an explanation would be useful if you wouldn't mind :)

Comment: @NewbieCoderAlert, explanation added.

Comment: ahh ok, I understand now, thank you for taking the time to explain it. Makes much more sense to me now. :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you change your appoach. Instead of showing and hiding certain items in your report, you could actually generate these items dynamically in JavaScript. Then you can only add the items when they are filled so that you would only have the relevant data. This way you don't have to look up each field if it is filled in and find it's corresponding paragraph in the report to show or hide it.

I also took the liberty to demonstrate a function which dynamically adds new `Room` and `PM` fields if you click the button. Same with the report, new fields are generated and added to the document.

The information from the form is collected with [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData). This API does some heavy lifting for you and can extract every *name-value* pair (read: each `textarea` element with its name and value) and store it in an object. This keeps your form dynamic and enables you to add and remove any `input` or `textarea` field that you want without having to modify your JavaScript. It simply gets **all** your data that is present in the form.

There were a couple of other things considering your HTML.

`input`, `select` and `textarea` fields can have a [`label`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label) element. This element is the descriptive name or title of your field. Use this to label your form elements.

[`id`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) attributes are meant to be unique. If there is more than one `id` with the same value in your HTML than every id, except for the first, with that value is invalid. Classes are more suitable to give your elements with shared styles or properties an identifier.

[Headings range from `h1` to `h6`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Heading_Elements). Technically you can have only **one** `h1` on your page. There are exceptions, when using `article` for example, but try to make the headings to have an hierarchy. Like a book you have a title (h1) and chapters (h2) and maybe smaller chapters in there (h3), and so on.

And a small note on JavaScript.

I suggest you dig into loops. Loops enable you to do the same thing as many time as you want while writing it only once. Like selecting multiple elements and toggling the class on each of those elements.

```
for (const textarea of document.querySelectorAll('textarea') {
  textarea.classList.toggle('darkmode');
}
```

The example above uses a [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop. Which can loop through every *iterable object*, *array-like object*, or arrays.

I understand that you are learning so I mean everything in a constructive manner. You are doing great. Keep it up!

It's a lot to take in and I hope that any of this is of help. If I have been unclear or you have any questions, please let me know.

Be sure to check out the example below.

```js
const form = document.querySelector('.js-form');
const pmContainer = document.querySelector('.js-pm-container');
const pmButton = document.querySelector('.js-add-pm');
const report = document.querySelector('.js-report');
const clearButton = document.querySelector('.js-clear-report');
const copyButton = document.querySelector('.js-copy-button');

// Clear the report
function clearReport() {
  while (report.firstElementChild) {
    report.firstElementChild.remove();
  }
}

// Clear report on clear button click.
clearButton.addEventListener('click', clearReport);

// Generate report based on values in the form.
function generateReport(formData) {

  // Create a list.
  const list = document.createElement('ul');

  // Loop over all name - value pairs in the form.
  // Each input has a name and a value associated with it.
  for (const [name, value] of formData) {
  
    // Don't do anything if the value is empty.
    if (value !== '') {

      // Create a list and two paragraphs.
      const listItem = document.createElement('li');
      const namePar = document.createElement('p');
      const valuePar = document.createElement('p');

      // Set the class and textContent.
      listItem.classList.add('gen');
      namePar.textContent = name;
      valuePar.textContent = value;

      // Append paragraphs to the list item
      // and the list item to the list.
      listItem.append(namePar);
      listItem.append(valuePar);
      list.append(listItem);

    }
  }

  // Add the list to the report div.
  report.append(list);
}

// On submit extract the values from the form
// and pass them to the generateReport function.
form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {

  // Collect the data in formData.
  const formData = new FormData(event.target);
  
  // Clear the report.
  clearReport();
  
  // Generate a report with the given FormData.
  generateReport(formData);
  
  // Prevent form from actually submitting.
  event.preventDefault();
});

// Generate new Room and PM fields and add
// them to the pm-container div.
pmButton.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  const html = `
    <label>
      <span>#Room</span>
      <textarea name='Room' cols="110" rows="6" value="" placeholder="Logs from #Room (if applicable)"></textarea>
    </label>
    <label>
      <span>PM</span>
      <textarea name='PM' cols="110" rows="6" value="" placeholder="PM Logs (if applicable)"></textarea>
    </label>
   `;
  pmContainer.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);
});

function copyRedirect() {
  copyClipboard(); // calling function copyClipboard()
  myFunction1(); // calling function myFunction1()
}

function copyClipboard() {

  // for Internet Explorer
  if (document.body.createTextRange) {
    var range = document.body.createTextRange();
    range.moveToElementText(report);
    range.select();
    document.execCommand("Copy");
  }

  // other browsers
  else if (window.getSelection) {

    var selection = window.getSelection();
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNodeContents(report);
    selection.removeAllRanges();
    selection.addRange(range);
    document.execCommand("Copy");

  }
}

copyButton.addEventListener('click', copyClipboard);

function myFunction1() {
  if (confirm("Your report has been copied to your clipboard, would you like to proceed to the forums?")) document.location = 'https://*******';
}
```

```css
label {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column
}
```

```html
<form name='myform' class="js-form">
  <h2> Report Generator</h2>

  <label>
  <span>Topic</span>
    <textarea name='Topic' cols="110" rows="2" value="" placeholder="Name, Infraction, Action Taken"></textarea>
    </label>

  <label>
  <span>Info</span>
    <textarea name='Info' cols="110" rows="6" value="" placeholder="Chatter Information"></textarea>
    </label>

  <label>
  <span>Summary</span>
    <textarea name='Summary' cols="110" rows="6" value="" placeholder="Report Summary"></textarea>
    </label>

  <div class="js-pm-container">

    <label>
    <span>#Room</span>
    <textarea name='Room' cols="110" rows="6" value="" placeholder="Logs from #Room (if applicable)"></textarea>
    </label>

    <label for="pm">
    <span>PM</span>
    <textarea id="pm" name='PM' cols="110" rows="6" value="" placeholder="PM Logs (if applicable)"></textarea>
    </label>

  </div>

  <button type="button" class="js-add-pm">Add PM</button>
  <button type='submit'>Generate Report</button>
  <button type="button" class="js-clear-report">Clear Report</button>
  
</form>

<div class="report">
  <h2>Generated report</h2>
  <div id="generated" class="generatedReport js-report">


  </div>
</div>

<button class="js-copy-button">Copy Report</button>
```

Comment: Thankyou, while this does work I would like to change the Generated Report so the headers have bb codes already attached e.g [b][size150]Info[/size][/b] Does this make sense?

Comment: it isn't recognising this part of the script as correct.   
```// Generate new Room and PM fields and add
// them to the pm-container div.
pmButton.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  const html = `
    <label>
      <span>#Room</span>
      <textarea name='Room' cols="110" rows="6" value="" placeholder="Logs from #Room (if applicable)"></textarea>
    </label>
    <label for="pm">
      <span>PM</span>
      <textarea id="pm" name='PM' cols="110" rows="6" value="" placeholder="PM Logs (if applicable)"></textarea>
    </label>
   `;```
am i doing something wrong?

Comment: If you can do the *bb code* styles in CSS I would recommend that, but otherwise sure. What browser are you viewing this in? *it isn't recognising this part of the script as correct.* with **it** you mean the browser, or your editor?

Comment: the editor, I'm using notepad++ and I used an online tester on w3schools and it didn't work there either.

Comment: I've tried the w3schools editor which works fine. Don't know about Notepad++. It should show a one long string. These strings are called [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) and make multiline strings possible and string interpolation (combining strings with variables) easier to work with. It is valid JavaScript. And it runs like it should as you can see in the code snippet above.

Comment: I know this has been a long time since I asked the question but I am needing to revisit this, I would appreciate if you could once again give me some advice Emiel.

Comment: If it's related to the answer above, I'd be happy to help. Otherwise I'd suggest that you create a new question.